# lock and unlock dispatch_queue_t in async task

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I want lock `LockQueue2` to complete process and when unlock `LockQueue2` show "number is :" `number` in `dispatch_after`.

I need this output :

> number set value 1
>   number is 1
>   number set value 2
>   number is 2
>   number set value 3
>   number is 3

```
let LockQueue = dispatch_queue_create("LockQueue", nil)

func test(num :Int){
  var number = 0
  let LockQueue2 = dispatch_queue_create("LockQueue2", nil)

  dispatch_async(LockQueue){
    LockQueue2.lock()
    // any process or waiting
    sleep(2)
    dispatch_sync(LockQueue2) {
             number = num
             print("number set value ", number)
           LockQueue2.unlock()
    }
  } 
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)){
     // any process or waiting
     sleep(3)
     dispatch_after(LockQueue2) {
         print("number is :", number)//*** show number set in last dispatch ***            
     } 
  }          
 }

test(1)
test(2)
test(3)
```

Comment: If you want a process on some random thread to wait for another, you'd probably use semaphores, not a lock. So, create a semaphore, have second process wait for a signal, and then have first process signal that semaphore. or use a serial queue.

Comment: Thanks dear @Rob, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with simple synchronous tasks, like you are, you can just use a serial queue:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.domain.app.serialqueue")
var number = 0

func simpleSerialQueue(_ num: Int) {
    queue.async { [self] in
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
        number = num
        print("number set value: ", number)
    }

    queue.async { [self] in
        let value = number
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("number is:", value) //*** show number set in last dispatch ***
        }
    }
}

simpleSerialQueue(1)
simpleSerialQueue(2)
simpleSerialQueue(3)
```

As you can see, I would let the queue coordinate my process, excising the use of semaphores or the like, which can be easily misused and result in deadlocks.

If the process in these tasks was, itself asynchronous, it might beg for other patterns (Combine, custom asynchronous `Operation` subclasses, etc.). But for simple synchronous tasks like this, a serial dispatch queue is adequate.

---

See [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36783292/1) of this answer for Swift 2 rendition.

Comment: It is very very Complete answer, section 2 solved my problem, very thanks.